# Physical_name without master access

Tags: sql-server

I am in a situation where I need to find the physical location of the data files for a single database.
Normally, I'd just do something like

```
SELECT name, physical_name  
  FROM sys.master_files WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = 'MyDB'
```

However on this particular server I don't have access to the master db, only MyDB.
  Is there any way to retrieve the info from MyDB?  This is on SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, filename
FROM sysfiles
```

Comment: That's it.  For some reason I was really struggling to find the right search string to get me to that answer.  Thanks!